# COALESCE in Nested Query

Tags: sql, coalesce

Trying to stop this query from returning NULL when the results (in this case, the lessons.classDate) doesn't exist. I'm sure COALESCE should be wrapped around but I can't get the syntax right.

```
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(S0001)* 100 / 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK))
        ) AS stat12wkMod1 
        FROM attendance_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK);
```

I was trying;

```
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(S0001)* 100 / 
        COALESCE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK)),0)
        ) AS stat12wkMod1 
        FROM stat_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK);
```

[EDIT]
Working version, for those interested.

```
SELECT IFNULL(FLOOR(COUNT(S0001)* 100 / 
    IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat_P01627
    INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
    INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
    WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(GETDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK)),1)) ,1)
    AS stat12wkMod1 
    FROM stat_P01627
    INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
    INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
    WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(GETDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK);
```

Comment: which database engine?

Comment: that's why you use isnull(field,1)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Isnull for SQL-SERVER and IFNULL for MySQL

```
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(S0001)* 100 / 
        IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK)),1)
        ) AS stat12wkMod1 
        FROM stat_P01627
        INNER JOIN lessons ON stat_P01627.lesson = lessons.id 
        INNER JOIN modules ON lessons.module = modules.id 
        WHERE lessons.module = 'MHG405294' AND lessons.classDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 WEEK);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

> The ISNULL OR IFNULL function and the COALESCE expression have a similar purpose
>   but can behave differently. 
>  Because ISNULL is a function, it is
>   evaluated only once.
>   
>  As described above, the input values for the
>   COALESCE expression can be evaluated multiple times. Data type
>   determination of the resulting expression is different. ISNULL uses
>   the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE follows the CASE
>   expression rules and returns the data type of value with the highest
>   precedence. 
> The NULLability of the result expression is different for
>   ISNULL and COALESCE. The ISNULL return value is always considered NOT
>   NULLable (assuming the return value is a non-nullable one) whereas
>   COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL. So the
>   expressions ISNULL(NULL, 1) and COALESCE(NULL, 1) although equivalent
>   have different nullability values. This makes a difference if you are
>   using these expressions in computed columns, creating key constraints
>   or making the return value of a scalar UDF deterministic so that it
>   can be indexed as shown in the following example.

Comment: what you mean you can't get 0? inner join requires explicit relationship between tables so it will return 0 when a relationship is missing

Comment: Mmm, incorrect parameter error? I've changed it to ISNULL((SELECT...),1)

Comment: can you please try the updated script.. isnull( (select) , 1)  ---> subquery requires a bracket inside the function

Comment: Sorry, still the same error. The brackets look correct. will edit OP with what it is now.

Comment: should be --------->   INTERVAL -12 WEEK)),1)
        ) AS stat12wkMod1

Comment: Yeah that's what I have, still says it's incorrect parameters for isnull.

Comment: i think the error is with the curdate()  what sort of db are you working at?  sql-server is getdate()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142018/discussion-between-darkmalice-and-masta-rhian).